# Overwriting in-code bindings with configuration file bindings for my IOC container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ninject

In the project we are working on, we are using Castle Windsor as an IOC container. At this moment we are specifying all our dependencies in a configuration file for flexibility.

Our config files are a bit big and to make the bindings more easily managable, I would prefer to put them in code. Of course, this means I lose a bit of flexibility to easily change certain bindings in production.

I was wondering if it is possible to let the bindings in the configuration file overwrite the bindings in code. This would mean I could specify all default bindings in code and then add a configuration file with a few exceptions if I want to change a binding in production.

Because I am using Castle Windsor, I'm interested if this is possible in Castle Windsor. However, we are considering to move to a different IOC container (e.g. NInject). So if another one can do such a thing much better, then I am also interested in that bit of information.

(PS: I'm also looking at automatic bindings, because most of our interfaces are just there for unittesting purposes and have only one class that implements it with the same name minus the "I". I'm even considering putting those interfaces in the same file as the implementation.)

Thanks in advance.

### Update

I found [a nice Ninject extension that will allow me to do automatic bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Projecting-Services-to-Bind) in exactly the way I want. I also found [a Ninject extension for doing XML bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml/wiki). However I cannot find if those XML bindings overwrite in code bindings.

Comment: I know that Autofac can do what you want - [here is the relevant documentation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/XmlConfiguration).

Comment: what do you mean by "binding"? What exactly would you like to be changing?

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic What I mean by binding is: the definition of which implementation `A` is returned when I ask the container for interface `B` (i.e. that `container.Resolve<B>()` will return an instance of `A`).

Comment: @MatthijsWessels: not sure about Castle Windsor, we use Unity and overwriting configuration is explicit - you call RegisterType to define bindings in code and LoadConfiguration to load bindings from xml file. It is up to you when and in what order you call these two methods.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So if I would just call LoadConfiguration after all the RegisterTypes then I would achieve that the config overrides the in code bindings. Unity seems like a good option then.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the flexibility I think you are after with bindings in code, but it might not be the type of design you would like...

I split up my functionality into modules (assemblies that have one, and only one, class that implements an IModule interface).  The implementation of IModule in each assmbly registers all of the implementation classes from that assembly into the DI container.  Then I have a module loader class that scans through assemblies looking for the IModule implementation for that assembly and calls the appropriate module loading method(s).  In this way, each assembly is self contained and I can literally drop in whatever assembly I want when I want to switch implementations.

With that ability, you can then decide how you want to split up your assemblies to be as granular as you want to swap out implementations.  This is very assembly heavy if you want a lot of flexibility and that is why it is not a strategy for everyone.

In my research, I found that the Windsor developers believe overriding bindings is a bad practice and therefore provide just about no ability to do so.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting approach. I was already planning to bundle the bindings with the assemblies, but didn't think about the fact that swapping out an assembly in production would also swap out all the bindings. The only situation that this doesn't handle is when you deliver an assembly with two implementations of an interface. One is bound in code (say, the old version) and the other (the new version) is not bound yet. The customer can then bind by configuration when his system is ready for the new functionality. Of course, that situation can be covered in another way.

Comment: One option could be to register the ListResover with your windsor kernel, expose a property on your interface of version, and then resolve all instances into a list.  Then you will have a list of services you can use and your code can chose the one you want based on the version property.  There may be a more elegant way to solve this that is transparent to your implementation, but I'm not sure how to do that off the top of my head.